# How do I add a 'Save' button to an Editor Grid Panel in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

I need to add a 'Save' button to my Editor grid panel. Everything I have tried does not work. Thanks for your help. Here is my code.

```
var iLineItemGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    id: 'iLineItemStore',
    store: iLineItemStore,
    cm: iLineItemCM,
    cls: 'iLineItemGrid',
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    frame: true,
    //title:'Edit Plants?',
    //plugins:checkColumn,
    clicksToEdit:1,
    viewConfig: {
        //forceFit: true
        autoFit:true
    },        
    tbar:  [{
        text: 'Add',
        tooltip:'Add the line item',
        handler : function(){
            var r = new iLineItemRec({
                i_line_item_name: '',
                i_line_item_amt: ''
            });
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            iLineItemStore.insert(0, r);
            iLineItemGrid.startEditing(0, 0);
        },
        //Should this be scope:this or scope:iLineItemGrid?
        scope:iLineItemGrid
    }, {
        text: 'Delete',
        tooltip:'Remove the selected line item',
        handler: function(){
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            var r = iLineItemGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCell();
            iLineItemStore.removeAt(r[1]);
        },
        //Should this be scope:this or scope:iLineItemGrid?
        scope:iLineItemGrid
    }],
    //MIKE SAVE BUTTON
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        tooltip: 'Click to save all changes to the database',
        handler: function() {
            iLineItemStore.each(function(record) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'UpdateInvoiceDataAction.do',
                    //ADD AN ALERT TEXT HERE TO TEST IT
                    success: function() {
                        iLineItemGrid = false;
                        Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'This record has been saved');
                    },
                    failure: function() {
                        iLineItemGrid.isLoaded = false;
                        cmh.display(action.result);
                    },
                    callback: function(records, options, success) {
                        //SOMEWHERE IN HERE POPULATE THE 'AMOUNT DUE' textfield
                        //How do I set this value?
                        Ext.getCmp('iAmountDue').setValue(Toa.Application.invId)
                    },
                    params: record.data
                });
            }
            )
        },
        //Should this be scope:this or scope:iLineItemGrid?
        scope:iLineItemGrid
    }]            
});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Does the button fail to get added to your panel, or does the button you've added simply not work as intended? Please add more detail about your expected behaviour so we can better assist.

Comment: Hello Daniel,  The button does not work as intended. I was thinking that I should make the save button apart of the tbar instead.